# "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping" after deploying

Tags: iis, automapper, automapper-3

Each time after I deploy my code into IIS I keep getting the error "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping".

Once I restart IIS, the problem goes away, so I don't think it's my code. However, today, I am continuing to get this error.

The mapping error initially happened in one place and after restarting, it is now happening on different mappings, so it's not always the same place.

Is there anything with a release into IIS that would cause Automapper to use a previously "cached" assembly, which would explain why when I restart IIS it fixes itself?

I'm pretty stumped here.

Comment: That's not easy way.  But you could download automapper source code and debug the exception in depth or add appropriate logging.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue after upgrading to 4.2.1. Happening suddenly in Production...not good. But yet sometimes it works...like you said, after restarting IIS website.

Comment: Do you still get this? If you solved, how did you solve it? Thanks